# Upload files using Curl php laravel

Tags: php, api, curl, file-upload

````
  $login = $this->logParsaSapace();```
  $loginToken = json_decode($login); ```
  $curl = curl_init();```
  curl_setopt_array($curl, array(```
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.parsaspace.com/v2/files/upload',```
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,```
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',```
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,```
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,```
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,```
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',```
    CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH => CURLAUTH_BASIC,```
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(```
      'path' => '/',```
      'file'=> new \CURLFILE('/C:/Users/parastoo/Desktop/gsd.sql'),```
      'domain' => 'dropbox.parsaspace.com'```
    ),```
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(```
      'Authorization: Bearer '.$loginToken->token,```
      'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'```
    ),```
  ));```

  $response = curl_exec($curl);```
  $curl_errno   = curl_errno($curl);```
  $curl_error   = curl_error($curl);```
  $info = curl_getinfo($curl);```
  $err = curl_error($curl);```
    if ($err) {```
    echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;```
    } else {```
    echo $response;```
    }```
  curl_close($curl);```
````

What is the problem with this code? It does not display an error and does not do its job properly and uploads the file. Does not display anything in the output.

Comment: Try not setting the content-type header

Comment: What has this code got to do with Laravel?